# Can I calculate the avarage of the top 15 values for each id in a table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with ID-s, a lot of date for each ID, and values for those dates.
I want to calculate for each ID the average values of the last 15 dates.

How can I do that in MSSQL?

Example:

```
ID | DATE | VALUE

1  | 2019 |  15
1  | 2018 |  14
1  | 2017 |  13
1  | 2019 |  15
1  | 2018 |  14
1  | 2017 |  13
1  | 2019 |  15
1  | 2018 |  14
1  | 2017 |  13
1  | 2019 |  15
1  | 2018 |  14
1  | 2017 |  13
2  | 2019 |  67
2  | 2018 |  54
2  | 2017 |  65 etc.
```

I want to have this table as a result:

```
ID | avg_of_last_15_values

1  | 43
2  | 56
```

It's just an example, the table is more complex and I have data about every 3 hours.

I haven't find anything about this in MSSQL, so I don't have a code for this yet.

Comment: how average of `id=1` is 43 in your above input same for `id=2`

Comment: I used dots to represent that there are more rows, but someone edited it so there are no dots. oO so there are more rows for id 1 and 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible approach to get the expected results. You need to number rows, just choose the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ID int,
    [DATE] int,
    [VALUE] int 
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
    (ID, [DATE], [VALUE])
VALUES
    (1, 2019, 15),
    (1, 2018, 14),
    (1, 2017, 13),
    (1, 2016, 13),
    (1, 2015, 13),
    (1, 2014, 13),
    (1, 2013, 13),
    (1, 2012, 13),
    (1, 2011, 13),
    (1, 2010, 13),
    (2, 2019, 67),
    (2, 2018, 54),
    (2, 2017, 65)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.ID, AVG(t.[VALUE])
FROM (
    SELECT  
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS RN
    FROm #Data
) t
WHERE t.RN <= 15
GROUP BY t.ID
```